# Why do I get a contradiction for this proof a sequence is decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}, \dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}, ...\right\}$

This is the continued fraction for $\sqrt{2} - 1$.

I was trying to prove that $x_n>x_{n+1}$ ie decreasing.

So I came up with recursive formula  $x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2+x_n}
\implies x_n=\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-2$

And here is my attempt to prove that it is decreasing:

for n=1, $x_1$=$\frac{1}{2}$, $x_2$=$\frac{2}{5}$ so this checks out

Now suppose its true for "n"

so if  $x_n$ > $x_{n+1}$

$\implies$
$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}$-2>$x_{n+1}$ from the recursive formula.

$\implies$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}$>$x_{n+1}$+2

$\implies$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+2}$>$x_{n+1}$

$\implies$$x_{n+2}$>$x_{n+1}$

Which is pretty much the opposite of what I was trying to prove...

Hints would be very appreciated so that I can retain my own sanity!

Comment: continued fractions alternate above and below the target value

Comment: Ah thats probably why my textbook said to consider "the two alternating subsequences"...

Comment: suggest you switch to the fraction for $\sqrt 2,$ where the "convergent" $\frac{p}{q}$ has only a few possible values for $p^2 - 2 q^2$

Comment: Even though it alternates above and below the target value, isn't this only true when n>N for some natural number N? I never made any restriction in my proof attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\langle x_n\rangle$ is neither decreasing nor increasing but it's "especial" subsequences i.e. $\langle x_{2n}\rangle$ and $\langle x_{2n+1}\rangle$ both are decreasing and have the same limit $\sqrt{2}-1$. Therefore , $\langle x_n\rangle $ converges to $\sqrt{2}-1$.